# Bootstrap 3 alerts dismissed with animation

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Is there a way to make dismissed alert in bootstrap have an animation like fade out?

I added the class `.fade` to the code:

```
 <div class="alert alert-info fade alert-dismissable">
      <p><b>Gracias</b> por ponerte en contacto! Responderé a tu correo lo más pronto posible.</p>
 </div>
```

But it doesn't work. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: for any of the answers below (except by [@guest](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23881533/1369473)), if you want to remove the `.alert` from DOM, `$('.alert').alert('close')` must be called

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can omit the data-dismiss attribute

```
<div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissable">
      <button type="button" class="close" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
      <p>animated dismissable</p>
</div>
```

and use the following jQuery

```
$(".alert button.close").click(function (e) {
    $(this).parent().fadeOut('slow');
});
```

or if you want clicking anywhere to close the alert use

```
$(".alert-dismissable").click(function (e) {
    $(this).fadeOut('slow');
});
```

Comment: Actually, if you want this to work, you should omit the data-dismiss attribute (you have no choice)

Answer (score 42):

you can add '.in' class, alert fade out.

```
<div class="alert alert-info fade in">
<a class="close" data-dismiss="alert" href="#">&times;</a>
<p>message</p>
</div>
```

Comment: A little confusing that adding the `in` class makes it fade **out** when closed, but nice answer. +1 for using built in Bootstrap functionality.

Answer (score 3):

`$('.alert-dismissable').fadeOut();` or assign a css3 fade out animation to your fade class and apply it to the `<div>` when you want it to fade out.

Answer (score 2):

You can listen to `close.bs.alert` event to use custom effects:

```
$(function(){
    $('body').on('close.bs.alert', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        $(e.target).slideUp();
    });
});
```

See in action at https://jsfiddle.net/6s8dgh72/8/

Answer (score 0):

you have to use class "fade show" it will work !

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.